# Can a simple (possibly weighted) graph be constructed for any given spectrum of the Laplacian?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Given a sequence $S$ of real numbers $0=e_0\le e_1 \le \dots \le e_n$, does there exist a simple graph G (possibly with real non-negative weights $\omega_{ij}$ assigned to its edges) whose Laplacian matrix $L$ defined as

\begin{equation}
    L_{ij}= 
\begin{cases}
    \sum_{k,\;k\,\text{is nbr of}\,i}\omega_{ik},& \text{if } i=j\\
    -\omega_{ij},                                & \text{if } i \text{  is nbr of } j\\
    0                                            & \text{otherwise}                           
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

has spectrum given by $S$ ?

Added later :
This problem is somewhat related to the problem of [Hearing the shape of a drum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum) except that **a)** The "drum" in this case is a finite graph with its "sound" being the spectrum of its Laplacian **b)** I am only interested in the **existence** of a finite graph for a given spectrum without concerning **uniqueness**.

Comment: Could you give more motivation to the question?

Comment: @Jakobian it is somewhat related to the problem of [Hearing the shape of a drum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum) except that a) The "drum" in this case is a finite graph with its "sound" being the spectrum of its Laplacian b) I am only interested in the existence of a finite graph for a given spectrum without concerning uniqueness.

Comment: I mean, you should edit your question and add all this information there.

Comment: I assume you require *non-negative* real weights $\omega_{ij}$? Otherwise $L$ describes an arbitrary symmetric matrix with eigenpair $(\mathbf{1}, 0)$ and the other eigenvalues are unconstrained.

Comment: @user7530 yes, you are right. I have edited the question to explicitly include non-negativity condition on weights.

Comment: The elements of $S$ are roots of some polynomial so they need to be algebraic. Apart from that and everything else already in place, I believe that no other constraints should be required